# How to create an object with two forms in two views which fills different fields?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have two views in my app (each with a ModelForm) and I want to create an object with the values returned by the two forms. How can I proceed?

views.py:

```py
def index(request):
    derog_indiv_form = DerogationIndividuForm(request.POST or None)
    if derog_indiv_form.is_valid():
        # Some code
    return render(request, 'derog_bv/index.html', {'derog_indiv_form':derog_indiv_form})

def raison(request):
    derog_raison_form = DerogationRaisonForm(request.POST or None)
    if derog_raison_form.is_valid():
        # Some code
    return render(request, 'derog_bv/raison.html', {'derog_raison_form':derog_raison_form})
```

forms.py:

```py
class DerogationIndividuForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Derogation
        fields = [ 'individu' ]
        labels = { 'individu': ('Individu :') }

class DerogationRaisonForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Derogation
        fields = [ 'type_derogation' , 'createur' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe split the `Derogation.type_derogation` and `Derogation.createur` in a separate `DerogationRaison` model and add a (nullable) `ForeignKeyField` to `Derogation`? (bit difficult to answer without knowing your UI flow/use case)